# Hide the Analytical badge for new sites

Tags: feature-request, badges, beta-sites, analytical-badge

The Aviation site just launched, into private beta. I was looking through the list of badges, and found a trusty old pal:

[image: Analytical Badge Screenshot]

The only thing is, this will never be awarded on a new site; can we get rid of it for new sites?

Comment: This is still the case four years later. :(